# Not work LoadBalancer after down scale on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently develop web applications on GKE.

I set up pods autoscaling to the environment.

When loading these pods, it scaled out as expected.(pods:1 -> 5)
After that I stopped loading and scaled down as expected.(pods:5 -> 1)
Then the page no longer appears.

Although it pings to the external IP of the load balancer, it does not respond to the request to the 80 port, so it seems not to be a routing problem of the load balancer.

I checked the load of the container, but the load was not particularly high.

After that, I manually scaled out pod to respond to requests.

Why does it stop responding to requests?

AutoScale setting file below.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler

metadata:
  name: autoscaler
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: frontend
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

Comment: Are you trying to say scaling-up starts failing after initial success? 
Can you please elaborate precisely what are you trying to achieve here, what is the issue? You may want to have detailed information about [GKE autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)

Comment: tanks.
Im saying "After down scaling, the application's responses made not working."

I found that it occurred because allocated memory and cpu were extremely low.

I think I will close this question because I seem to have solved it. Thank you very much.